# What is the difference between Geoprocessing Map object vs. MapDocument object in Python

Tags: python, arcmap, mxd

I have the following code:

```
mxd["C1"] = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(fRoot, filename))
mxd["C2"] = [arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(fRoot, filename))]
```

C1 creates a geoprocessing Map object

C2 creates a MapDocument object

What is the difference between them in terms of functionality and/or limitations?

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000000n000000

UPDATE: Still not really sure what the difference is but found out in order to run my program I required to have geoprocessing Map objects and not MapDocument objects.

Things like mxd.save(), and assigning the dataframe only seem to work with the geoprocessing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the same exact thing in both instances. Nothing to see here, move along.

When you print an object in Python, it runs the [str](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=repr#str) operator on it*. `str(MapDocument)` says something like `Geoprocessing Map Object` or whatever. When you do `str(list)` it will use the [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/repr.html#module-repr) operator on each item in it, so it will get something like `[<arcpy.MapDocument object at 0x00000000>]` where the `<...>` part is what `repr` returned. Both `str` and `repr` are simply string representations (with different implicit semantics) of the same thing, this object implements both and returns something slightly different for either.

*Note: As an implementation detail, in CPython it will actually go through the native `tp_print` method in most cases which is functionally the same thing.

Comment: Interesting -- I wonder why they decided to call it a "Geoprocessing Map Object" instead of a "Geoprocessing Map Document Object", since a map document has 1 or more maps (data frames).

Comment: Because I didn't think it was a big deal when I wrote it? :)

Comment: Funny, got me wondering what a map object is called! See below.

Comment: Nice answer, I guess I was wrong in assuming it was analogous to the ArcObjects counterpart. I hope naming does turn into another ADF fiasco.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an example of the output of str() and repr() given a MapDocument object:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\Samples\data\BloomfieldTownship\BloomfieldTownship.mxd")
>>> repr(mxd)
'<MapDocument object at 0xde68d0[0x53fa520]>'
>>> str(mxd)
'<geoprocessing Map object object at 0x053FA520>'
```

And for the map (data frame) object:

```
>>> df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
>>> repr(df)
'<DataFrame object at 0x5420670[0x5434688]>'
>>> str(df)
'<geoprocessing Data Frame object object at 0x05434688>'
```